# Ajax pending all requests until timeout from real device (android)

Tags: android, jquery, ajax

I'm frustrated with this issue, trying to create an ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url : "http://10.0.50.19:3000/something",
        contentType: "application/json",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json'
```

})

And the result is a pending request, no matter if I address a real url or just a fake one ( to get an error ), all I get is this pending request.
Also tried jsonp, PORT request and adding header to the request. Below image is from debugging real device in chrome://inspect :

[image]

Of course the device connected to the internet and no special application is running on it to block the access.

Comment: you can follow this url without ajax?

Comment: does it matter? I tried both existing and non existing links, if I try from the desktop computer to create ajax I get either 200 or 404, but from the device I get a pending request with no answer..